# css3 margin doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, css, semantic-ui

I use Semantic UI for creating navbar, this is my header.php code

```
<div id="mainHead">
  <div class="ui pointing menu fluid four item inverted " id="menu">
    <a href="index.php" class="item">
      <i class="home icon"></i> Home
    </a>
    <a href="about.php" class="item">
      <i class="user icon"></i> About
    </a>
    <a href="portfolio.php" class="item">
      <i class="archive icon"></i> Portfolio
    </a>
    <a href="contact.php" class="item">
      <i class="mail icon"></i> Contact
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui labeled icon button black">
    <i class="icon list layout"></i>
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my style.css code

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "helvetica", arial;
}

#mainHead {
  margin: 40px 40px 0 40px;
}

#menu {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

navbar is displayed and has a max-width 1024px, but not in the middle of the screen, alredy is fixed to 40px from the left edge of the screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n51D.png)

but if I delete the "item four fluid" from heder.php get this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeRYV.png)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: please try explain what the problem is more. Why you delete something. Maybe you should not use margins, try use position:relative, left:40px;

Comment: does not set me left and right margins on auto, only up and down on 0px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So , you want to have the menu in the middle keeping each item's width same as is now, right ? If so, you can set the value of the property 'margin' of #menu to '!important' like below

```
 #menu {
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
```

instead of

```
#menu {
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

This is because, there are margin-left and margin-right property set to 0 with '!important' which override your margin of #menu.

Comment: Thanks very, very much! Now works! I never would have thought of it. Thanks again!